# lftp mget with wildcard mis-identifies a file

Tags: wildcard, lftp

I'm running into an issue that's perplexing to me.  I'm using LFTP as part of a nightly automated file transfer process, with the goal of collecting all of the .csv files on a site.

Generally, the `mget` command, coupled with a wildcard `.csv` is able to find and download the files I expect it to. However, I'm running into an interesting situation where I have a file, which is identified with `ls` as:

```
-rw-------   0 User Name -         6461 Oct  4 14:04 file name.csv
```

but when I run mget *.csv, I get the following error message:

```
mget: Access failed: 550 /path/to/file/4 14:04 file name.csv: No such file or directory.
```

It looks like it's appending the `%d %h:%m` portion of the file's metadata to the file name when trying to mget it. I've thought it might be due to spaces in the file name, but in a testing it it doesn't look like that's the case.

**Summary**

- The file exists, as checked by `ls`
- The file should be captured by the `mget` command
- The file is not captured by the `mget` command because somewhere along the line between the search and get commands, additional characters get added to the front of the file name, causing it to try to get a file that doesn't exist

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question ends up being server and version specific, but I'll share what ended up being the problem in case it leads to someone else not having a trove of problems in the future.

FTP servers have different mechanisms for escaping users' names. In this case, the operations user account had a two part first name, with space separation.

The way(s) in which the FTP server do (or do not) escape user names can lead to everything being thrown off a column by the regex parser for mget in lftp. Reducing the username to a value which was compliant with lftp's expectations (appears to be one word, can include `_` and `-`) ended up resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use wildcards with lftp you need to specify the full path to the files.  When trying to download from the EBI FTP server the following will not work

```
lftp -c 'open ftp.ebi.ac.uk; set xfer:clobber on;  lcd /export/data/blastdb/temp/ ; mget nr*.tar.gz
```

Adding the path with your mget call allows the wildcard expansion and works as one would expect..

```
lftp -c 'open ftp.ebi.ac.uk; set xfer:clobber on;  lcd /export/data/blastdb/temp/ ; mget /pub/blast/db/nr*.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the correct directory or you misspelled the file.
You can brute force and download the whole arborescence with the command :

```
lftp> mirror .
```

By the way, your error might be that there is a space in the name of your file.

```
lftp> mget file\ name.csv
```

Although, the wildcard should expand correctly the space with \_space